# Ordering of events in structured streaming window aggregates in append mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am facing an issue in structured streaming with spark.

Current setup :  I have a datastream coming from kafka. Each message has an eventtime. I am using these eventtimes to make window aggregates and a watermark rule to discard state.
The mode of output is append mode.

Aim: I need to get the window aggregates in order as they expire so that I can process these events in order of eventime windows. I expect the windows state to expire sequencially because of my sliding window.

Problem: Some times the order of messages printed is not sequential on basis of windows . For ex

|[2020-06-11 08:02:00, 2020-06-11 08:03:00]|

|[2020-06-11 08:01:00, 2020-06-11 08:02:00]|

Why are the windows not dropped in order? I wanted this to be ordered . 
Please help

Comment: How many partitions does your Kafka topic have? And if it has more than one, how is it partitioned?

Comment: Do you mean my source kafka topic? Both the source and sink kafka have a single partition only .

Comment: Sorting operations are supported on streaming Datasets only after an aggregation and in Complete Output Mode.

Comment: @thebluephantom why cant i sort values in a micro batch ? I dont want to sort across batch , I want to sort in a micro batch

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the architecture (yet). Many posts here on SO allay that notion.

As cricket_007 states in numerous posts, you can best leave the sorting to the down-stream system(s) in general. It is also more flexible that way, the whole notion of the RDBMS is that fixing the data sort order is less valid - clustering aside.

If you look at this use case https://mapr.com/blog/real-time-analysis-popular-uber-locations-spark-structured-streaming-machine-learning-kafka-and-mapr-db/ then you see that sorting plays no role. That said, I see many requests, but many can achieve the goal without sorting.

Single Partition Topics are an outcome for lower volumes, providing the sort order is set by the 'producer' and that order is acceptable. Also, you can consider KSQL and writing to a single partition KAFKA Topic to read in from subsequently or KAFKA Streams with Java, Scala.

I think the issue is that as from a post I saw a few years ago:

> The basic tenet of structured streaming is that a query should return
>   the same answer in streaming or batch mode. We support sorting in
>   complete mode because we have all the data and can sort it correctly
>   and return the full answer.  In update or append mode, sorting would
>   only return a correct answer if we could promise that records that
>   sort lower are going to arrive later (and we can't).  Therefore, it is
>   disallowed.

Comment: I need to detect sequential patterns in my data , so that is only possible if i buffer , sort and then process data in the micro batch .

Comment: I need to do sequential pattern detection in a micro batch basically

Comment: Life is not always what we want it to be

Comment: Yes, you are right . Btw old Dstream api allowed sorting these micro batches right with the .transform method?

Comment: yes, but it is legacy, so not relevant. Unfortunately. Most Sp Str Str can be done without sequencing, but may be an slightly diff mindset reqd. Success. Upvote would be nice